# Apartment Building

Tags: code-golf, ascii-art, random

Draw an "apartment" building according to the specifications below.

### Basic Rules

Take, as input, the number of floors of the building.
Return a building with that many floors meeting the following specifications:

The building will be eight characters wide, with eight underscore characters (`_`) on top and eight dashes (`-`) on the bottom.

The first floor of the building will always look like this: `|  ||  |`.

As long as the building has more than one floor, the top floor will always look like this: `| ---- |`

All floors in between must be randomly selected between the following:

`| -  - |`

`|  []  |`

`|__  __|`

### Example Outputs:

5 floors:

```
________
| ---- |
|  []  |
| -  - |
|__  __|
|  ||  |
--------
```

2 floors:

```
________
| ---- |
|  ||  |
--------
```

1 floor:

```
________
|  ||  |
--------
```

### Specific rules

Your inputted number of floors will, at minimum, be 1.

You may output as a string, a list of strings, a nested list of characters, or any other output format in which the position of each element is clear.

All floor types must have a nonzero chance of appearing at any given level (other than the bottom and the top), but they do not have to be uniformly randomly chosen.

Code-golf, so shortest code wins.

Comment: Is it allowed to use different characters to represent `_`, `-`, `|`, `[` and `]`?

Comment: I don't think that should be allowed, since it's ascii-art.

Comment: Is there a minimum maximum number of floors? That is, is it okay if my program doesn't accept floor numbers past a certain amount (say 127)? Also, do imports need to be included?

Comment: Imports should be included, I believe (check the standard rules, though). As long as you can accept a reasonable number, it's fine. Only accepting 3-floor buildings would not, 127 or less is fine. You have to handle the 1 and 2 floor case though.

Comment: For languages without a PRNG built into it, can we accept a list of pregenerated random numbers instead?

Comment: Sadly, no. https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/15026/108673 implies not.

Answer (score 6):

## x86-64 machine code, 68 bytes

```
B8 5F 5F 5F 5F BA 7C 20 2D 2D AB 0F C8 3C 5B 75 02 B0 5D AB B0 0A AA 0F C7 F0 9E B8 7C 20 20 5B 72 0C B8 7C 20 2D 20 74 05 B8 7C 5F 5F 20 92 FF CE 7F D7 B8 7C 20 20 7C 74 D0 6A 08 59 B0 2D F3 AA 88 0F C3
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##jVNdb5swFH22f8UdU4RpSJVkXVWRZC973sueJoUocmwDrsBGmLRkTf76sgskrGqnaUICc8/HPb4YMUmFOJ@5K4DBd4/R2zS3O55DQpOIFPYJFG9CYP7Wv5k201l/BbSHZAcdfTiCD/5y@dAuJriY3V9X87uA2oi42jpJyc4987K1pEQUJfA8BH/tU/JoFLikd@2KG5@6ZJAN5dgguS3uKKlkxY3szRzPLupL3DeZYMi0vmQijwLkvyR/tgGD5OdfJdurZPtOIiPSiCzt@TguSqQSoJxGsxTs/0U@vuqPknLvMnhYkNKWUInm1XQmOJxKlXAZUFtfV1JvQhB5i9Q08CBY0CerJSRMZLy6AReCNjUYrNOP2oh8LxUsXS21vc2@UNqCBdeGBfQFvxpqoFJun9frz7P5ZkFJYitgnQWsYLbAx3KF@cCMx5gZNSRhvSLsuhBSVkhPmDfSUWxGLjax8RALL8Yt50QHVmy@cZFpPCHCShV5Ldy2a7DdNIQDvkoLL1c6jKbzH2h3WDG2N06nRknothokwboZjzfB4gTPmc4VsAN8QJPm66fWdHBgIw27Q61c0AVrEDydz79EkvPUnSfF/R3e8JdZIV/lvwE)

Following the standard calling convention for Unix-like systems (from the System V AMD64 ABI), this takes in RDI an address at which to place the result, as a null-terminated byte string, and takes the input number in ESI.

In assembly:

```
.global f
f:  mov eax, ('_'*0x01010101)  # For the first line.
    mov edx, ('|' | ' '<<8 | '-'<<16 | '-'<<24) # For the next line.
o:  stosd       # Add EAX to the output string, advancing the pointer.
    bswap eax   # Reverse the order of the bytes of EAX.
    cmp al, '[' # Check if the low byte is '[' ...
    jne sf      # ... and if it is ...
    mov al, ']' # ... change it to ']'.
sf: stosd       # Add EAX to the output string, advancing the pointer.
    mov al, '\n'# Set AL to a line feed.
    stosb       # Add that to the output string, advancing the pointer.
    rdrand eax  # Put a random number in EAX.
    sahf        # Set flags from AH (its second byte).
    mov eax, ('|' | ' '<<8 | ' '<<16 | '['<<24) # One of the possibilities.
    jc d        # Jump if CF=1.
    mov eax, ('|' | ' '<<8 | '-'<<16 | ' '<<24) # Another possibility.
    jz d        # Jump if ZF=1.
    mov eax, ('|' | '_'<<8 | '_'<<16 | ' '<<24) # The third possibility.
d:  xchg eax, edx   # Exchange registers.
    dec esi     # Subtract 1 from ESI, counting down from the input number.
    jg o        # Jump back if the number was >1 before the subtraction.
    mov eax, ('|' | ' '<<8 | ' '<<16 | '|'<<24) # For the lowest floor.
    jz o        # Jump back if the number is 0.
    push 8; pop rcx  # Set RCX to 8.
    mov al, '-' # Set AL to '-'.
    rep stosb   # Add AL to the output string RCX times, advancing the pointer.
    mov [rdi], cl   # Add the low byte of RCX, which is now counted down to 0.
    ret         # Return.
```

Answer (score 5):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), <s>47</s> <s>46</s> 44 bytes

*-2 thanks to [Kevin Cruijssen](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/52210/kevin-cruijssen).*

```
'_4×I≠i"| --"¹ÍF"| - |  [|__ "3äΩ]„| º'-4×»º
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f9fPd7k8HTPR50LMpVqFHR1lQ7tPNzrBmIq1CgoRNfExysoGR9ecm5l7KOGeTUKh3ap6wLVH9p9aNf//6YA)

Comment: [44 bytes](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f9fPd7k8HTPR50LMpVqFHR1lQ7tPNzrBmIq1CgoRNfExysoGR9ecm5l7KOGeTUKh3ap6wLVH9p9aNf//6YA) by doing the mirror at the end.

Answer (score 5):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal), 41 bytes

```
‹¨2[`  [ - __ `²℅|ð2-]\|p;‛| m4-½J\_4*pøm
```

[Try it Online!](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/#WyIiLCIiLCLigLnCqDJbYCAgWyAtIF9fIGDCsuKEhXzDsDItXVxcfHA74oCbfCBtNC3CvUpcXF80KnDDuG0iLCIiLCIzIl0=)

```
‹¨2                      ;                 # Dyadic map (val, index) to...
   [                 ]                     # If the index is truthy (i.e. not first)
    `  [ - __ `²                           # String literal "  [ - __ ", made into a square (chunks of 3)
                ℅                          # Choose one of these
                 |   ]                     # Else... (first)
                  ð2-                      # " --" - Take a space and append two -s
                       \|p                 # Prepend a |
                           ‛| m            # Take "| " and mirror it
                               4-          # Append four -s
                                 ½J        # Split that in half and append
                                   \_4*p   # Prepend "____"
                                        øm # Vertically mirror (flipping []) and join by newlines
```

Answer (score 5):

## [Python](https://www.python.org), <s>102</s> <s>139</s> <s>136</s> ,<s>134</s> 117 bytes

```
lambda n:[8*"_","| ---- |",*choices(['| -  - |','|__  __|','|  []  |'],k=n)][:n]+[2*"|  |",8*'-']
from random import*
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=LY1BCsIwEEX3nmLIJmlMwboqhZ4kDaG2jQZtEtJ0IeQmbgqid_I2ptbhw_-84c883u4eLtYsT1U3rzmovPzMt3Y89S2YipcUScRQhDwNRMRod7G6GybCcYKQFDHDUUoAKX8RgAtIVLBrbTLBKyP2_EjTjbVfUpxjsVPejuBb0yfTo7M-0P9zqqwHDdqs6_NAClYcssp5bQKhiuiMTYOrUWNQtjWWZfMv)

Thanks to @Steffan for pointing out I can't read. Now outputs the correct apartment

-3 bytes thanks to @Steffan
-2 bytes from me
-17 bytes thanks to @loopy walt

Comment: > As long as the building has more than one floor, the top floor will always look like this: `| ---- |`

Comment: Also: > The first floor of the building will always look like this: `|  ||  |`.

Comment: @Steffan Wow ok my reading comprehension is not doing great today. Will fix my answer

Comment: `(1,2)[n>1]` can be `(n>1)+1`

Comment: You can save a loop by using `random.choices`: https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=LY1BCsIwEEX3nmLIJmlMwboqhZ4kDaG2jQZtEtJ0IeQmbgqid_I2ptbhw_-84c883u4eLtYsT1U3rzmovPzMt3Y89S2YipcUScRQhDwNRMRod7G6GybCcYKQFDHDUUoAKX8RgAtIVLBrbTLBKyP2_EjTjbVfUpxjsVPejuBb0yfTo7M-0P9zqqwHDdqs6_NAClYcssp5bQKhiuiMTYOrUWNQtjWWZfMv

Answer (score 4):

### C++, 281 bytes

```cpp
#include<random>
#include<string>
using t=std::string;t a[3]={"| -  - |\n","|  []  |\n","|__  __|\n"};t f(int n){std::random_device g;std::uniform_int_distribution<int>d(0,2);t s("________\n");if(n>1)s+="| ---- |\n";for(int i=2;i<n;++i)s+=a[d(g)];s+="|  ||  |\n--------";return s;}
```

I didn't want to use the standard C `rand` and `srand` functions, so here I go with the standard library of C++.

Comment: Here's a port to TIO (using `rand` because it's code golf): [212 bytes](https://tio.run/##bVDRToMwFH3fV5xgNG0Qde5JCvuCxTef5kIYg9lkK4ReEpPBt@Nth3NRT5qmp/fcc25bNE1UHHKzH8cbfWzqlpKtJvtoaVeE4cPHctZZbfaglG/i2FLLTBHy9WKTnoIeEXj17ya4Z4L1Bt8ky4Asc2RgfSW0IRh5IlgRZBO4KJWuhFnOpQ1TZ8fwDqqqW9@j02elE6PCUDtNvm5zsxPydrFR5xb0vQ@NJgSqLalrDawaRudwzLUR8jQDw/pu0sdSvL6tVlIqf81hOKeZXfmJFE9qOiaY8xmc7qjE2cbByYml0zwv4VxdalefBcuaSpD8VS3qjpAk8FsQuydfBH6cvKMaRW0s4Q4HbUrEsNcD/LFyoh@T4f@84JI0zIbxCw)

Comment: And here's a port to TIO (not using `rand`): [270](https://tio.run/##dVHRboJAEHznKzY0ae6CtlqTNnrAj1hzoXDSS2Qx3NK0Ub7d7gFV09oNgdvdYWYY8v1@mu8yLE@nO1vt64biN0vu0VGRR9HDexq0zmIJlPBktXLUcKcIsvVikxzCI0yBr@MrhhNuYL2Bn0ZrAK190zF@KywSoDz0NE2GRV3pwnzY3ECp@mGLdls3lWagLqxXemvJ1hjzIC3EbPIkmciJUI/F1FLZrcB0Ll2UeDNcvb5ipl7RJk/KxqiiyHpMti5EKTdqgMPx2NudjhWqxlDbIDjVcRyY79rCQGxrNmOyKg0usyGI68nwTWkQeNkqsyjkIQCuG1/MD3XZVTRfLhcv0GApeCOkvFr@m8r1q8xvXLsjTV97k4LHPYv5BJYjEzPAEAcW5hMSmKnxGMOcz5yO7yQMjn15NDFy4GJrI9XZ2JAAOMZsBf3e5nVLEMfQ38KV/yVnQO8ma6mGvEZHcA87iwZW4K4N/KHyoAtJd1svPCt1QXf6Bg)

Comment: Building on @Noodle9 [266 bytes](https://tio.run/##dVFhb4IwEP3Or7iwZGmDbjqTLVrgjzjTMKisiRyGHssW5be7KzA1m7s0pXf3eO/1mu/303yXYXk63dlqXzcUv1lyj46KPIoe3tOgdRZLoIQrq5WjhjNFkK0Xm@QQHmEKvI6vGE44gfUGfhKtAbT2Scf4rbBIgPLQ0zQZFnWlC/NhcwOl6ost2m3dVJqBurBe6a0lW2PMhbQQs8mTZCInQj0GU0tltwLTuXRR4s1w9PqKmXpFmzwpG0UxKg/J1oUo5UY1htoGwUXe8/HYe56OEaqOR4H5ri0MxLZmIyar0uBSG4ZwXRnukwaBl6wyi0IeAuC4cVv@qEuvovlyuXiBBkvBHSHlVfPfiVz/yvzGtTvS9LU3KXjcs5hPYDkyMQMMo8DCfEICMzUeY5jzOYr6TMLg2IdHEyMHLrY2Up2NDRMAx5itoN/dvG4J4hj6LVz55zgDejdZSzXkNTqCe9hZNLACd23gD5UHXUi623rhWakLutM3 "C++ (clang) – Try It Online")

Answer (score 4):

## [Perl 5](https://www.perl.org/) `-n`, 110 bytes

```perl
@a=map{('| -  - |','|  []  |','|__  __|')[rand 3]}1..$_;@a[0,-1]=("| ---- |","|  ||  |");say for'_'x8,@a,'-'x8
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##JcvRCsIgGAXge5/iRwI3UNHGYDAGvkBPIPIjVBDUFNdFkb16f0aHc@C7OflUriORi8st5lcnKihorUI2gg/wJyIAYhW9L3E9whDeVusdzi56I5UNS8fbswUql41Qf@P9vMUnnFMRKB6TdFEK1UA0sIlZtv@kfL@kdSN1GLWxhtT6BQ)

Comment: I'm never sure if you appreciate the extra golfing or not, but I've played with this and managed to get it down to 94 bytes: [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##FcxBCoMwFEXReVbxBuJXTEKiCA5Kd9AViHwCbaHQmhA7sBi33tTeyZndcIvPPufFfXD3kZjWQVYvF7bqRGmDOoKEAv5gnADJDDDvic61GAsuS9tEN1/RTbvRumDV1pISkGhtJanjmHMnBmFF@/Xh/fDzktWl18aarOYf "Perl 5 – Try It Online"). I'm going to play with another idea I have but I don't think I can beat this approach...

Answer (score 4):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), 36 bytes

```
×_⁴⸿Ｅ⊖Ｎ⎇ι‽⪪| - |  [|__⁴| --⟦|  |⁴⟧‖Ｍ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Rc0xC8IwEIbh3V9xZLpAuunU1cVBkdqtSonpiYEkLWcqCPnvMUXR8Z6D9zN3zWbULucj2xCxtZ4eKHqhYC1lvfqoOLP4HXs94ZYMk6cQacBdmOZ4mP2VGKVU0BIHzS@0ChodhtHjaXK2RBJUkAC61H/zCharhPwvdUUgLe9LsYZujkzcW@axxOucN7l6ujc) Link is to verbose version of code. Explanation:

```
×_⁴⸿
```

Output four `_`s and then move to the start of the next line.

```
Ｅ⊖Ｎ⎇ι‽⪪| - |  [|__⁴| --
```

Output `| --` for the top floor, but randomly choose between `| -` , `|  [` and `|__` for intermediate floors.

```
⟦|  |⁴⟧
```

Output the left half of the ground floor and the ground.

```
‖Ｍ
```

Reflect to complete the building.

Answer (score 4):

## Excel, <sub><s>143</s></sub> 142 bytes

Anonymous worksheet function that takes input from cell `A1` and output to the calling cell.

```vb
="________
"&If(A1>1,"| ---- |
","")&Concat(IfError(Choose(RandArray(A1-2,,1,3,1),"| -  - ","|  []  ","|__  __")&"|
",""))&"|  ||  |
--------"
```

### Example Output

[image]

Answer (score 3):

## JavaScript, <s>168</s> <s>153</s> <s>151</s> <s>149</s> <s>147</s> <s>146</s> <s>140</s> 136 bytes

-13 thanks to Steffan, -2 by emaneresu A, -2 by myself, -2 by myself, -1 by myself, -6 by tsh, and -4 by me

```js
n=>`________${[...Array(n-1)].map((_,i)=>`
|${[` -  - `,`  []  `,`__  __`,` ---- `][Math.random()*3|!i*3]}|`).join``}
|  ||  |
--------`
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ZYpBCoMwEEX3OcUUukjEBKx0VSz0AD2BhExQaSOaSJRCaTx7GsFN6eMPfN6fXr/03HgzLdy6tou6ira6oto5fmohxM17/aaWF0yKUU@Uqtyw9EVC2hE4pGCOALWErSgFoNRmeAJQ1ne9PIXXtnUjZVkZDiYr5RqQid4Zi7iSABC2I3wHY@Ps7IZODO5BNT0zdiG/6vSviqTiFw)

Comment: [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ZY3RCoMgFIbvfQqRLnRMWY3dbNTYA@wJRFQqtqI0LAYj9@zOqJuxn3MO///xw2n1S4@la4aJGlvVIejc5IWSm5LZ0PSqgIc0CvolZzEnM2eM3ZzTbxwJEazXA5Z5wVGswjge7aOFXMDVSgmhlB4JftfTkzltKttjsjv6gyCstY1RQH3UGaH1xJfQLwvoJhVKa0bb1ayzD6zxiZAL@EXZP0ojCl8 "JavaScript (Node.js) – Try It Online") for 155 bytes

Comment: Actually, [153 bytes](https://tio.run/##ZY3RCoMgFIbvfQqRLnRMWY3dbNTYA@wJRFQqtqI0LAYj9@zOqJuxn3MO///xw2n1S4@la4aJGlvVQefB5IWSm5LZ0PSqgIc0CvolZzEnM2eM3ZzTbxwJEazXA5Z5wVGswjge7aOFXMDVSgmhlB4JftfTkzltKttjsjv6gyCstY1RQH3UGaH1xJfQLwvoJhVKa0bb1ayzD6zxiZAL@EXZP0ojCl8 "JavaScript (Node.js) – Try It Online") because the `a=` does not have to be included in the byte count. [Relevant meta post](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/6940/92689).

Comment: [151](https://tio.run/##ZY1NCsIwEEb3PcUQukjEBH9wo7TiATxBCEloi7a0SUmLII1nj5HWhfiYGb55DEyjH3ooXN2P1NiyCjoLJsuVXEgnSs1ZJR5oBPx3TyfOGLs4p5/YEME63WOZ5RzFQ4jl0TpG4ALmKCWAlB4JftXjnTltStthstr7jSCssbVRiXqpI0LziA/BfzqhCyoU1gy2rVhrb1jjAyGn5Fft/tU2qvAG)

Comment: [140 bytes](https://tio.run/##ZYxBCsMgFET3OYWFLjREIQ1dFQM9QE8gop8ktIZEgwmFUnt2a8BN6WMGhreYEZ6wdt4sG7WuHyLwaHmrVeb4Foyxq/fwwpbWRLIZFoxVZQhvhS4Coigl6GrfSEiUt1IIKZU9TSQvxQ22B/NgezdjUjbhYMpGEjY6Y7X@7A9hb0EzOnbOrm4a2OTuGPCZkEvxq07/qk4qfgE)

Comment: @tsh brilliant, but why `!i * 3`? I replaced it with `0` and saw no difference. (**Edit:** When given input 2, your version remains constant, which I suppose is the reason behind it?)

Comment: @code The top most floor have `i==0`, so `!i*3` is 3. And `...|3` becomes 3. So we choose the last one in candidates. when `i>0`, `!i*3` is 0. And it is the same with previous codes.

Comment: [122 bytes](https://tio.run/##ZYxBCsIwEEX3PcUILpLGFLS4UVNP4AlCyIS2tJGaSFvcGM8eU@hGfPyBz@Mzd/MyUz3a58ydb9poRHSiQr2CjHTCiooxe3FXzML2LRE4pOAOAaSCpWgNkMbJ8ASgkjcz98VoXOMfhOZl2Ni8VJ@ArCOWntIjgLBcxleQIsbau8kPbTH4jhhypPSc/arDv9onFb8)

Answer (score 2):

## [Java (JDK)](http://jdk.java.net/), 160 bytes

```java
f->{var b="________\n|"+(f>1?" ---- |\n|":"");for(var r=3;f-->2;r=3)b+=" -  - ,  []  ,__  __".split(",")[r*=Math.random()]+"|\n|";return b+"  ||  |\n--------";}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##NU9BbsIwELzzipFPDiZWaW81SW@VeuDEEVDkAKGmiRM5GwQivD3dUDqyNbvr0Yz3ZM82Pu1/Blc1dSCcuNcduVIXnd@Rq72emsmutG2LpXUetwnQdHnpdmjJEtO5dntU/CZXFJw/rrew4dhGDynw5enzabX4E6S4JEMRp7ezDcgTkT2x8b1QskjnHwIxA/04eRciMkUd5KgOyZsp4jh9NVxFuUpYCT4zgGMxyzIgy4Rum9KRFDMRrcM0WVr61sH6fV3JaKvEw9eEA3XBI1cC6HuMafETwtwH8/g9B0M6T3BIMDdMC@YXLpT63xBYXVs6VLruSDe8IZVeOiU2XqiLtk1TXqWLxp4n0Z/vfTLe@/AL)

Answer (score 2):

## Google Sheets, <s>162</s> 159 bytes

```
="________
"&IF(A1>1,"| ---- |
","")&JOIN("",ARRAYFORMULA(IFERROR(CHOOSE(INT(RANDARRAY(A1-2)*3)+1,"| -  - ","|  []  ","|__  __")&"|
","")))&"|  ||  |
--------"
```

[image]

*-2 bytes thanks to Taylor Alex Raine*

Comment: Your answer almost looks like an apartment building...

Comment: You can use `Int` in place of `Floor` to drop two bytes

Answer (score 2):

## [C++ (GCC)](https://gcc.gnu.org), <sup><s>182</s> <s>177</s></sup> 168 bytes

```cpp
#import<ios>
auto f(int i){std::string s(8,95),t[]{" -  - |","  []  |","__  __|"};if(--i)for(s+="\n| ---- |";--i;)s+="\n|"+t[rand()%3];return s+"\n|  ||  |\n--------";}
```

This requires gcc's `#import` directive.
`95 == '_'`, so `std::string(8, 95)` constructs a string of 8 `'_'`.

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=VVJLasMwEKVL6xSDQoNUy9D0A2ns5AQhu64cY4w_icCWgiSnizgn6SabQrvogdrTVHZUQoYZGN783oz0_p3v6lb3lm7y_HT6aE0VTH8-R7zZSWUiLvUCZa2RUBEuDHB60KaYzbRRXGxAkyl7eabMxMkBQwBWO8wwQJzA4KUpQJp2-BjyigQBp5VURPtzvBYdBFZsVmjxkDoQ-yZWmSgIvX1MQlWaVgnQ_pAPXW9rETjB4fHM9_dmNeIir9uihJ6yUWXWLNAFy7eZyqXYX2HnHRYI2cVQk3ExbJipTc6gL4A76-_jhKID8vpQVUupNAMOc5iEyIIVkD4fInigyPMc3SGmhy0Mb0qyel0uKe3BQoLt5Q0nrJRs0n6OJsMcnjBwDvhgydWl-I9Q5obbLq48l62BKLLvcokc4W3L6xKI73PLaaA2HgO5KsCXAwbBWmAGkzM5x_4-RO6sX_ETA6vTxP2LPw)

Answer (score 2):

## [C (GCC)](https://gcc.gnu.org), <s>213</s> 179 bytes

*-31 bytes thanks to [@ceilingcat](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/52904/ceilingcat) and @JuanIgnacioDíaz*

*-3 bytes thanks to [@c--](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/112488/c)*

```c
p(x,i){for(i=9;i--;x/=8)printf(L"\n| _-[]"+x%8+!!i);}c;main(n){srand(&n);scanf("%d",&n);for(p(4793490);--n;)p(c++?L"\x592c8\x4d848\x91290"[rand()%3]:374472);p(294984);p(7190235);}
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=LY9RqsIwFES3ooE-7qWGV9NbmvuCuAF3oCIlpZIPY6g-CKgr8ad-uAJX425s1a-Z-Tkzc73bzdbarrv_Hxupn48AceLw1OxbcDM2TkoTf2caQ-v8sYGFWPnzaCOXa5HGRKfjsUNzsWZXOQ8eT4e28jX8eDQHW_kGRFKLyRAHYAAqOSfO0EjpDQawaTrvkbFgZfUqUq2pF54qzsTyjcIkX__lJVGp0ARQTKxpcOWUM5UXfftn-vdBd6OPeQE)

Answer (score 2):

## [Perl 5](https://www.perl.org/) + `-n -M5.10.0`, 93 bytes

This is based on golfing [@Xcali's answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/247485/9365).

```perl
say for"_"x8,(map{(<"|{ ---- , -  - ,  []  ,__  __}|">)[$_-2&&1+rand 3]}2..$_),"|  |"x2,"-"x8
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##FcxBCoMwFEXReVbx@IgoJsFEBAelO@gKRD6BtlBoTYgdWIxbb2rv5MxuuMVnn/PiPrj7SEzrIKuXC1t1orRBHUFCAX8wToBkBpj3ROd6LFjZsjRNdPMV3bRbrQuuJSUg0WolqWOYcycGYYT9@vB@@HnJas7q0mvT6vYH)

---

## [Perl 5](https://www.perl.org/) + `-n -M5.10.0`, 97 bytes

```perl
say$_.reverse=~y/[/]/r for'_'x4,(map{(<'|{ --, - ,  [,__ }'>)[$_&&1+rand 3]}0..$_-2),'|  |','-'x4
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##DczRCoIwFADQ933FfRhepd3NaUIP1R/0BUOG0ILA3JgRibNPb3U@4AQXxy7neVi4ldG9XJzd6bMoo3oV4eYjWnzvRfkYwloeMa1AJIBAABhhLWx4rgy3RaF3cZiu0PZbLSW31FQCE0BCgfQfcm7ZgWnWfH143v00Z7p0stZ1pukH)

Not smaller, but a reasonably different approach that might have potential for more golfing...

Answer (score 2):

## [JavaScript (Node.js)](https://nodejs.org), 136 bytes

Tied with [@code's solution](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/247475). Used the `!i*3` trick to shorten my own solution. Go vote up their answer because mine would be worse without theirs.

```javascript
n=>['________',...[...Array(n-1)].map((_,i)=>['| -  - |','|  []  |','|__  __|','| ---- |'][Math.random()*3|!i*3]),'|  ||  |','--------']
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##fYtBCsIwFET3niKu8lOaD7W4kgoewBPEEEJtNaVNSloEIXeP0XbTjcN8GOb96fRLT7U348ytuzexraKtzoKqVTRHRJHu4r1@g@UFkzjoEUDlhn0/A@EkOdA8RSIkWaJShCi1tDwptVJc9fxEr@3dDcCyMuxNVkr2G4awDPkqKmPt7OT6Bnv3gBaODDtnLNCbpYyddlt6@EuLLY0f)

Answer (score 1):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), <strike>164</strike> 161 bytes

```python
from random import*
def b(n):
	yield"_"*8
	if n>1:yield"| ---- |"
	for _ in range(n-2):yield choice(["| -  - |","|  []  |","|__  __|"])
	yield"|  |"*2+'\n'+"-"*8
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##RY5LDoMwDETX4RRWNiR8pEI3FYteBFBUfsWoOChig5S701ioqjcej0fP3o59tnQ/z8nZFdyLhtBw3azbk2gYJ@gU6SoSB46fQRqZPCKBE9CzqC7LQx4KvIzEZB0YQGLMe1SUl/oKQT9b7EdVcxqA01mQULdwSWMAjPGy1b9LnjdJmcYNxanMw92T8fjHF1lx48/YXtjuFPIsNoe0qyWgLiUbkvr8Ag)

Python generator for the win.

Improvement 1 : Removed unnecessary white-spaces. Thank you @jezza_99 for the suggestion.

Comment: [-3 bytes](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=RU9LDoIwEF3DKSbdUFASYWVI9CJAGvlUSnRKmrog4SZudKF38jZ2UomzmTdvXt6bub-n2Q4aH4_Xzcp0_3lKo69gTti5pq6TNjYJu15CwzEuwmBW_aVjgiX7MFAS8JgVnlogdQULCwOpDQhQSDbnnmOax14E7aBV2_OS1ACk3joIZQ0eCgEgxMLqeE1aaJPkm6jCaMNSl_s79EAp6p-SbbMdHUj0SHTDFc3BZBRaPjpHj1iFLPYm69df) by removing unnecessary whitespace

Answer (score 1):

## [Factor](https://factorcode.org/), <s>139</s> 138 bytes

```factor
[ dup [ "________", 1 > [ "| ---- |", ] when 2 [-] [ { "|__  __|""| -  - |""|  []  |"} random , ] times "|  ||  |", "--------", ] f make ]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##NU9BDoIwELz7iknPYhT1oolX48WL8YSkaWANFWixlHgQ345bxJl0s9mZ3UzvKvPWDdfL6XzcoSRnqEKtSuLii7EsrMvJodKenKpaOGVyW6OlZ0cmoxbaYj@bvbFixsw1Ntgy4yU@Q4K8a5BAyAlizrZDmPSIGOh5kuJVkOHdJEpZerMoJSBlL4INCDbukKTg7vMPETa9rjlEEPvw@JqIJoyX77//pBxF3IzAw2qDxmnjYSrWM1s3tiWQyorhCw)

Answer (score 1):

## [Pip](https://github.com/dloscutoff/pip), 63 bytes

```
P'_X8Fi,DaPi?RC" -  -   []  __  __"<>6'-X4WRsWR:'|P"|  |"X2'-X8
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m724ILNgwYKlpSVpuhY37QPU4yMs3DJ1XBIDMu2DnJUUdBVASCE6VkEhPh6ElWzszNR1I0zCg4rDg6zUawKUahQUapQijICCFhBjoKYtjjaNhTIB)

#### Explanation

Roof:

```
P'_X8
P      Print
 '_     Underscore
   X8   Repeated 8 times
```

All floors except ground floor:

```
Fi,DaPi?RC" -  -   []  __  __"<>6'-X4WRsWR:'|
Fi                                             For i in
  ,Da                                          Range(argument decremented):

      i?                                        If i is nonzero (not top floor):
        RC                                       Random choice from
          " -  -   []  __  __"                   This string
                              <>6                Split into sections of size 6
                                                Else (top floor):
                                 '-X4            Four hyphens
                                     WRs         Wrapped in spaces
                                        WR:'|   Wrap the whole string in pipes
     P                                          Print it
```

Ground floor and ground:

```
P"|  |"X2'-X8
P              Print
 "|  |"         That string
       X2       Repeated 2 times
         '-X8  Hyphen repeated 8 times
               Last expression is autoprinted
```

Answer (score 1):

## [SWI-Prolog](https://www.swi-prolog.org/), 177 bytes

```
N+[A|T]:-length([_|X],N),A='________',-X,append(X,['|  ||  |','--------'],T).
-X:-X=['| ---- |'|T],+T;+X.
+X:-X=[A|T],random_member(A,['| -  - |','|  []  |','|__  __|']),+T;1=1.
```

Recursion, recursion, recursion.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Jc3LCsIwEIXhvU8xZDUDk9KNm6qP0KwLoQwRqxZyKbHQTd69NnpW3@KHs@Tk00t/tnnfHfbU6bi@WzQsLMQeDbG59s2pqtPm1vIz5eBWVAX0MSiKrRnpkl18pCBhCvcp48BgawHwKw6CHeFPEQCRokbiLc/r5CMO1NT7MzVf)

Answer (score 1):

## [PowerShell](https://github.com/TryItOnline/TioSetup/wiki/Powershell), <s>111</s> <s>109</s> <s>102</s> <s>96</s> 93 bytes

```powershell
'_'*8
for($x=' ---- ';--$args[0];$x=' -  - ','  []  ','__  __'|random){"|$x|"}
'|  |'*2
'-'*8
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##JY5BCsIwFET3/xRDiH4tDWg3iqUnKeVTsdFF20iKWGh69hj1MYthBoZ5unfnp0fX91FbVFgiC2dnss7v9FwxTAJcGqNbf5/qQ1P@YyRxzkDd4GtEABEOvh1vbtgvKug5qJU4AIGzgtik3bgSnXIqcjqGDRZCQo2v4dp5OAvbO@enC7SoX7VNn7TQGj8)

Answer (score 1):

## [Befunge-93](https://github.com/catseye/Befunge-93), <s>194</s> 189 bytes

-5 (me) small optimistions

```
&&\52**+052*"________">:#,_$:1`#v_>0"--------"52*"|  ||  |">:#,_@
>:#,_$1-:! #v_02vv"| ---- |"*520<0
^"|__  __|"<    5>:#,_$2-:    #v_^
^"|  []  |"? <* <>#5 #2 #0    #< ^
^"| -  - |"<>    ^
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##LczBCsIwDAbg@57iN5EdqoWuUA@lVN9DXUWY3rzZU9@9Jm4/JJDwJc/l9f28l97H8Ra8MQcnncoWQo58LPs4PbiW7MhuIVUNaFr0R5dhtZONO4h2PtQqRrkYE7xLmIeZWilAKY0SNGY98zbqJIcrAq53/X1GQuYENuAA9mAHGTdkAX2esix6d8PpBw)

Takes a two digit integer from stdin as input. Note that for some reason, in TIO the integers have to be on two lines.

Answer (score 0):

## C (gcc `-w`), 162 bytes

```c
*a[]={"| -  - |","|  []  |","|__  __|"};f(n,r){r=rand(srand(&n))%3;puts("________");for(n>1&&puts("| ---- |");n-->2;)puts(a[r++%3]);puts("|  ||  |\n--------");}
```

Test main:

```c
int main(void) {
  int i;

  for(i=0; i<100; i++) {
    f(i);
    puts("");
  }
}
```

Technically, it's not genuinely random, but every level type has a chance of appearing at every level. [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##NU1dC8IwDHzfrwgFR@MsTH2M849so5TJpKBROj8etv11a7bpkYTjcrk05tw0Ma5dWRe9GsCA1KA2QqGsYaHWAlg7qJFazZuAfSiC45Pu5pky4mpP9@ej08r@oJDaW9B83KbpspFsgQQisTHHHeGsuzJk2WpfI/1tMExdsflBDsbo@QFX51m/bv6E0CcAk@QpETZ98kVOkGX@sM1zWgyy0B5pZvcg9lariitWszYmY/w07cWdu2jeXw)

Comment: As per Code Golf SE tradition, please add your language and byte count to a header at the top of your answer.

Comment: Oops, forgot. Sorry!